# Onsen UI: getting can't use form with tab bar

Tags: onsen-ui

In Onsen UI ( http://onsenui.io/ ), I am using form with a submit button. It works as expected. But when I put submit in footer the form stops responding.

Here's [a link](http://codepen.io/vineshhpatel/pen/lupwE) showing the original code.

```
<div class="content-padded">
    <ons-button modifier="large"
                onclick="">
      Save
    </ons-button>
  </div>
```

Here's [a link](http://codepen.io/vineshhpatel/pen/pxBFv) showing the problem.

```
<ons-tabbar class="content-padded">
    <ons-button modifier="large"
                onclick="">
      Save
    </ons-button>
  </ons-tabbar>
```

I am not able to figure out why it is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks!

I'm not sure why tabbar would cause the components unresponsive. Maybe this is a bug?

But you could get around it by not using "tabbar" and use "ons-bottom-toolbar"

```
<ons-bottom-toolbar>
    <ons-button modifier="large"
      onclick="">
        Save
    </ons-button>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. the link takes me to a graphic thing, 100% not related to the code.
2. Maybe it's out of scope that the button from the form? without seeing a complete code, it's hard to tell... can you provide a complete code rather than just the button code? if it's part of the large code base and can't be shared, then try to replicate the issue with smaller code...then post it.